# Is Anti-Forgery token needed in Server to Server communication?

Tags: security, asp.net-core-webapi, csrf, antiforgerytoken, websecurity

I have a REST API based on ASP.NET Core 3.1. This API will is called by other servers, currently there is no client application which calls this API.

In such a scenario do I need Anti-Forgery tokens? Also if its needed how inject anti-forgery tokens in a Server-to-Server communications scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an [offical document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-3.1) about csrf.

A CSRF token is generated based on Http Session. If your API endpoint is relying on a cookie /or some mechanism to reestablish the session.You need to prevent CSRF attack.In the official link,you can see the example of CSRF attack,it includes an authentication cookie.

Comment: I think that clarifies it. Thanks!